# I need a non template solution

Tags: c++

I have a class defined like this

```
class A
{
private:
   map<int,vector<int>> m;
public:
   vector<int> GetJsonVal(int k)
   {
       return m[k];
   }
};
```

I would like to change it into something like this

```
template<class T>
class A
{
private:
   map<int,T> m;
public:
   T GetJsonVal(int k)
   {
       return m[k];
   }
};
```

However, I have many other places that plainly use only type `A`, so if I change my class into the latter, I have to fix a lot i.e change all into `A<type>`, which I don't want. In those places I simply do `void func(A*p)` or `A& r=....`

So, how can I both use i.e `A<float>` and `A` anywhere I like ?

Answer (score 3):

So, the easiest and most legible solution that comes to mind is a [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template <typename T>
class Tool {
  private:
    map<int,vector<T>> m;
  public:
    vector<T> GetJsonVal(int k) {
      return m[k];
    }
};

using A = Tool<int>;
```

And so now the old code can continue using `A`, and all new code can use `Tool<int>` or another type alias.

Answer (score 1):

You could use type-erasue, but will still need to update the code here and there... An approach could be doing something like:

```
class A {
   map<int, boost::any> m;

   template <typename T>
   T valueAs(int idx);
};

A a;
a.valueAs<int>();
```

You would have the implementation verify that the type stored and the type retrieved are the same. Then you would probably want to go to all existing uses of `A` and enforce the check (or check the potential error).

That is, if you want to support mixed types inside `A`... if you each `A` can only hold a particular type, you can just make a `ATmpl` type with the contents in the question, and then `typedef ATmpl<vector<int>> A;`. At this point you would still have to fix some use cases (specifically: forward declarations)...

Answer (score 0):

Use template class specialization, I would say

```
template <> class A<vector<int>>
{
    // all your old code here
}
```

should work...

UPDATE

Just to be clear, there is a semantic difference between template specialization and type alias. With template specialization you could put your (true and tested and bug-for-bug compatible) code into specialization and use new and shiny (but potentially buggy code) elsewhere in new production, and later when you fill it is good enough you could remove specialization and use only new code. With type specialization it is new code everywhere right away...